# continuous integration for many languages

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to setup a continous integration system that upon a commit or similar trigger should:

- run tests on a fortran/C/C++ code, if needed.
- compile that code using cmake.
- run tests on a rails app.
- compile the rails ap.
- restart the server.

I'm looking at Jenkins. Is it the best choice for this kind of work? Also, what's the difference between using a bash script that makes all that (if possible) and using jenkins? I'm asking not because I'm thinking about using a script, but to better understand jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Jenkins would certainly be a reasonable choice for this. Apart from the ability to run arbitrary scripts as build steps, there's also a large number of [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins), which provide better integration with cmake for example.

Even if you're using a single bash script to do all of this, using Jenkins on top of it would still have a number of advantages. You get a web interface, email notifications and build history for free, with all that this entails. By integrating your tests "properly" with Jenkins, you can also get things like graphs that show how many tests succeeded/failed over time.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Jenkins for java projects and have to say it is easy to configure. I used to add lots of plugins for better configuration of build steps, but tend to go back to using scripting languages for build and deploy steps because of two main reasons. If I have a build script, it's easier to configure the same job on a different Jenkins server or run the script manually if need be and the build configuration is not so cluttered (I still have one maven job with more than 50 post build steps). The second reason is, that it is easier to version the scripts in SVN, compared to having the build config in SVN.

So to answer your questions. I don't know if it is the 'best' tool, but it is good enough for me. Regarding scripting: use each tool for what it is build for. Jenkins a glorified cron deamon with great options when it comes to displaying analysis. The learning curve for people to use it is minimal (i.e. starting a job, seeing whether it failed.) Configuring Jenkins needs a little bit more learning, but it's very easy to set up simple jobs and go then to the more complicated tasks.

Answer (score 1):

For the first four activities Jenkins will do the job and is rather the best choice nowadays, but for things like restarting the server (which is actually "remote execution"), better have a look at:

- http://saltstack.com/

or:

- https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home
- http://cfengine.com/
- http://puppetlabs.com/
- http://cfengine.com/

Libraries like Fabric(Python) or Capistrano(Ruby) might be useful too.